# How to change props.data in dependence of inner component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[ProductPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ngeN.png)
[MainPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbT3r.png)

I want to click on product on MainPage and Open info about it on ProductPage. I want to open exactly that product, that i had clicked on MainPage.

I have an App.js with router. When I click on ProductCard component in MainPage i want to open ProductPage exactly with that props, that shows in ProductCard. How can I do this?

App.js:

```
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/LoginPage" component={LoginPage} />
              <Route exact
                path="/"
                render={() => <MainPage data={data} />}
                //data={data}
              />
              <Route path="/RegistrationPage" component={RegistrationPage} />
              <Route path="/ProductPage" component={ProductPage} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

MainPage:

```
<div className="product-cards">
  {props.data.map(function(item, index) {
    return <ProductCard key={index} data={item} />;
  })}
</div>
```

ProductCard:

```
<a className="a" href="/ProductPage">
  <div className="card-block">
    <img
      className="image-style"
      src={props.data.url}
      alt={props.data.name}
    />
    <span className="product-name">{props.data.name}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

ProductPage(shows error):

```
  <div className="product-page">
    <hr className="hr" />
    <div class="product-description">
    <img src={props.data.url} alt={props.data.name}/>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what error exactly ?

Comment: change `<Route path="/RegistrationPage" component={RegistrationPage} />` to `<Route path="/RegistrationPage" component={() => <RegistrationPage data={data} />} />` if I got it right.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: it is unclear what is it exactly you want to accomplish.  please provide more information with regards to your intentions.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't passing any props to Product Page which is causing error.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/LoginPage" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => <MainPage data={data} />}
      />
      <Route path="/RegistrationPage" component={RegistrationPage} />
      <Route path="/ProductPage" 
        render={() => <ProductPage data={data} />}  />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>;
```

Comment: I want to pass to my ProductPage only that data, that i clicked on MainPage.

Comment: Easy fix is to add Route to ProductPage nested inside MainPage component.